# Convert Multiple Colums into an Array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to convert the following data:

```
(existing table)
client | red | green | blue | shiny | damaged
tom    | 0   |   0   |   1  |   1   |    0
john   | 1   |   1   |   0  |   0   |    1
```

I have created a new table that I want to "replace" the old table colums with:

```
id | name
1  | red
2  | green
3  | blue
4  | shiny
5  | broken
```

effectively doing this

```
client | colors
tom    | [{1,0},{2,0},{3,1},{4,1},{5,0}]
john   | [{1,1],{2,1},{3,0},{4,0},{5,1}]
```

Then in my php script, I could decode the array and format the data accordingly.

Any ideas or am I just completely confusing everyone?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't really make sense of your question here. Why would you want data in that format? That's completely useless from a relational perspective.

Comment: It seems like you want to go from a bad design to a worse one, with our help. I'm reluctant to oblige

Comment: It looks like you want to have a many-to-many relationship here which normally involves three tables. One for colours, one for clients, and one for the relationship between those including metadata like counts.

Comment: I'm really trying to find a way to be able to easily add additional "options" (colors) without having to go back and manually specify these options to list them on many different pages, such as an edit page, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is a true many-to-many situation.  Based on the colors "red" ,"green", "blue", I believe OP is trying to represent each client's color as a *combination* of the three primary colors RGB.  I further suspect that what OP wants is not to change their underlying *database structure*, but rather the user interface for manipulating those values.

Comment: The database has nothing to do with RGB primary colors actually, I was just using this as an example. In truth, I don't know what I want haha! What the database actually holds is character traits that are yes or no currently. I've edited my original post to further explain this.